# How to project additional column after using parse and mv-expand in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Here's a sample for string column, I would want to split this string column into multiple columns based on the key values of dictionary and if there are more keys, I want to make them into different rows.

````
<column2>: "for each user:[{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":"ABC"},
{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":"ABC"}]"```

I want to trim initial string "for each user:" and create columns for id, publisher, type, Identity.Id, Identity.sid, roles, permissions, name and since there are two dictionaries in the above sample, I want to insert the second item into a new row.

I also want <column1> in the output
````

Comment: You got two different answers below. Please review them and accept the one that helps you (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If you're still missing info, please add a comment describing what's missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
datatable(Column2: string) [
    'for each user:[{"id":1,"Publisher":null,"type":0,"Identity":{"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","sid":"134567890"},"roles":[],"permissions":[],"name":"ABC"},{"id":1,"Publisher":null,"type":0,"Identity":{"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","sid":"134567890"},"roles":[],"permissions":[],"name":"ABC"}]"'
]
| parse Column2 with 'for each user:' Json:dynamic '"'
| project Json
| mv-expand Json
| evaluate bag_unpack(Json)
```

Result:

| id | Identity | name | permissions | roles | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | { "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "sid": "134567890" } | ABC | [] | [] | 0 |
| 1 | { "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "sid": "134567890" } | ABC | [] | [] | 0 |

Step by step explanation:

1. Use `parse` to extract the json part that you're interested at into a column named `Json`
2. Project only the `Json` column (as you don't care about the original input string)
3. Use `mv-expand` to split the array in the `Json` column into separate elements (each one will get his own record)
4. Use `evaluate bag_unpack(Json)` to have a separate column for every key in the `Json` column

Answer (score 1):

````
print message = ```<column1>: "val",
<column2>: "for each user:[{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":"ABC"},
{"id":1,
"Publisher":null,
"type":0,
"Identity":{
"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"sid":"134567890"},
"roles":[],
"permissions":[],
"name":"ABC"}]"```
| parse message with * '<column1>: "' column1 '"' * '<column2>: "for each user:' dict:dynamic '"'
| mv-expand dict
| project dict.id, dict.publisher, dict.type, dict.Identity.Id, column1 // add the rest of your properties of interest
````

| dict_id | dict_publisher | dict_type | dict_Identity_Id | column1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | val |
| 1 |  | 0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | val |